# Check if url exists in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to validate a URL using python3 for that I've used following code,

```
import requests
request = requests.get('https://validators.readthedocs.io/en/latest/')

if request.status_code == 200:
    print('Web site exists')
else:
    print('Web site does not exist')
```

This works well for most of the website except for SharePoint url. For example the following URL `https://<tiny>.cc/waxxtz` (remove `<>` between `tiny` before using it!) returns `Web site does not exist` even though it does.

Is there a reliable way to test if URL exists in python3?

Answer (score 0):

It is because the page returns status code 404. A non 200 status code does not mean that a website does not exist.

If you want to find out if there is a website available for a domain, making a DNS request is a better option. If there is a webserver available for that domain, you will get an IP or a CNAME entry as response. If it doesn’t exist, you should see an NXDOMAIN as response.

Comment: well, I tried this 
`import dns
import dns.resolver

result = dns.resolver.query('https://<tiny>.cc/waxxtz', 'A')
for ipval in result:
    print('IP', ipval.to_text())` but it also returns `NXDOMAIN` (remove `<>` before using it)

Comment: Try it without the scheme and path, just the domain name. 
So something like result = dns.resolver.query('<tiny>.cc’, 'A')